# Get orientation of scroll given AccessibilityNodeInfo

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am creating a script that explore different android applications. If the script finds a scrollable component during the exploration this one must be scrolled. The problem is that sometimes the scroll direction can be horizontal or vertical and I would like to know it before perform the scrolling action.

Given an AccessibilityNodeInfo of a scrollable component (e. g. RecyclerView), is it possible to know in which directions the RecyclerView is scrollable (vertical or horizontal)?

Answer (score 0):

The presence of ACTION_SCROLL_UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT is the API that gives you this information. Unfortunately, the original API of ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD/BACKWARD is very common and doesn't tell you which direction. So, like pretty much everything in the accessibility API, it depends on the app and widget sharing the information with you.